# You can listen to the entire podcast over on Luminary if you want to

Tags: prepositions

1. *You can listen to the entire podcast **over** on Luminary, if you want to.*

Is it necessary to use the preposition "over" in this sentence? What about this:

2. *You can listen to the entire podcast on Luminary, if you want to*.

Comment: No, it is not necessary. **Over** serves to indicate some kind of distance, whether physical or figurative, and adds nothing to your sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not *strictly* necessary.

Over serves to indicate some kind of distance, whether physical or figurative.

There seems to be a semantic advantage of including the word, because it's reminiscent of the following sentence:

"We're at Grandpa Joe's farm now, but you can head on **over** to Jimmy's place, and get the tractor."

It indicates a distance between two similar type places.

If you don't add "over", and someone isn't already clear about Luminary, then "You can listen on Luminary" might mean that Luminary is a device, like a tablet or mobile phone. Luminary is in a completely different realm of existence. However, when you say "over" then it means "We're on one website here, and you can go to that other similar website there."

On the same topic of "is it necessary?"

> "if you want to"

is certainly not necessary.

So, the entire sentence is written in a friendly colloquial style.